# What are some language exchange phrases?

Tags: spoken-korean, resources, phrase-request, phrases

What are some good resources for learning phrases for a language exchange? Where should I start?

Comment: Hi user2374 - can you share a few more details? Is this someone who you are going to stay with, or just talking on the internet? Rough idea of age group?

Comment: this looks like a good question for the chatroom

Comment: I didn't know there was a chatroom. Its just talking in like a study group setting. I'll be learning Korean from them while teaching English.  Everybody is a young adult except a couple older adults.